# Twilio: Change caller ID based on number called?

Tags: twilio

I have two numbers that forward to a single phone, one work number (A), and one personal number (B).

(A) was setup using Twilio to forward to my phone.

Is there anyway to have some sort of caller ID indicator letting me know which number is being called? That way I can distinguish whether the incoming call was for my work or personal number.

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

This depends on how you have it set up.

If you have your office and personal line ring a twilio number you would do something like this

---

First you would add a verified outbound caller ID with twilio

https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223180048-Adding-a-verified-outbound-caller-ID-with-Twilio

Then you on an inbound call you would grab the id of the number called. It will be listed as the To number.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call

Then when they call the phone you are forwarding it to you would just specify the To number from before as the From number.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls

If you have a different set up or would like to have twilio make an announcement instead of showing that caller ID there are other work arounds for those methods too. Just let me know and I can edit my answer.

Comment: The setup that you describe of Twilio making an announcement is exactly what I'm trying to achieve. I'd love it if you answered my question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64639846/multiple-twilio-numbers-forward-to-single-number-how-do-i-indicate-to-operator