# Multiple twilio numbers forward to single number, how do I indicate to operator what number was called?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-programmable-voice

My parents-in-law are opening a second business, but want to be able to answer calls from customers on their cell phone. They are having multiple twilio numbers forward to their cell phone. The problem now is that they don't know which business the customer is calling for, so they don't know how to answer the phone.

In a perfect world, when the phone is answered, I'd be able to play a message to the operator telling them the name of the business called, before actually connecting the calls together. Ideally their Caller ID would continue to function as well, so they could see who called them in their call history etc. I'm open to other suggestions as well.

I'm a seasoned programmer, and have only tried out Twilio Studio so far, and I didn't have much luck.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio Studio doesn't currently support the `<Number>` noun, [URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/number#attributes-url) parameter. You can use the Studio [TwiML Redirect Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/twiml-redirect) however.

You can reference this [blog](https://www.twilio.com/blog/voice-mail-human-detection-studio-functions), that utilizes the TwiML Redirect Widget to play a prompt to the dialed party and expects a response, for voicemail avoidance. You can modify the the code to meet your requirements.

[image]